# \mathbbm in exponent of equation

Tags: symbols, equations

I am trying to put a blackboard `1` (indicator function; I'm using the [`bbm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbm) package) in the exponent of an equation, something like

```
\begin{align*}
  f(x) = \mathbbm{1}(x = 1) \\  % works
  p(x) = q^{\mathbbm{1}(x = 1)} % does not work
\end{align*}
```

I've also tried putting in a `\protect` before `\mathbbm`, to no avail. The error is

```
dfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex (file bbm8): Font bbm8 at 600 not found
```

EDIT: As several kind commenters have pointed out, this code compiles in isolation. I have determined that the source of problem is likely something in my style file since changing the document class to `book` works just fine.
Any pointers of what to look for in the `.cls` file?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the font, I can actually get your code to compile. Take a look [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bbm). Also, does your title imply that `\mathbbm` works when not used in an exponent ?

Comment: @zuggg yes, \mathbbm works when not used in an exponent. My example above definitely works in isolation, so I'm trying to whittle down my actual document to something minimal that still breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Load the [`bbm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbm) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\[p(x) = q^{\mathbbm{1}(x = 1)}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is *exactly* what the OP mentions they're using...

Comment: @Werner. Correct, I'm using the package. But in all fairness, my minimum example above does compile correctly. I'm in the process of creating a minimum example that displays the behavior I'm seeing in my full doc.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error if I didn't have the `texlive-bbm` package installed (this is on a Fedora machine). It might just be that there's a missing font file that only turns out to be a problem in certain contexts.

Comment: @Werner That information wasn't there when I answered the question. `:)`

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this problem except on sharelatex.com; will contact the maintainers of that site. Thanks all!